# Unit testing supposed to be "passed"? Why is it failing?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tdd

```
  function renderInventory(inventory) {
  //create a flat list
  var flatList = '';
  //iterate over the inventory
  for (var i = 0; i < inventory.length; i++) {
    var designerObject = inventory[i];
    var shoes = designerObject.shoes;
    //iterate over the each shoe in the array
    for (var j = 0; j < shoes.length; j++) {
      var currentShoe = shoes[j];
      //add the designer name, the shoe name, and the shoe price and the new line
      flatList = designerObject.name +", " + currentShoe.name +", " + currentShoe.price + '\n';
    } 
  }
  //return the flat list
  return flatList;
}
//assertion Function
function assertEqual(actual, expected, testName) {
  if (actual === expected) {
  console.log('passed');
  } else {
  console.log('FAILED [' + testName + '] Expected "' + expected + '", but got "' + actual + "'");
  }
}

//test cases

var currentInventory = [{
    name: 'Brunello Cucinelli',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'tasselled black low-top lace-up', price: 1000},
      {name: 'tasselled green low-top lace-up', price: 1100},
      {name: 'plain beige suede moccasin', price: 950},
      {name: 'plain olive suede moccasin', price: 1050}
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Gucci',
    shoes: [
      {name: 'red leather laced sneakers', price: 800},
      {name: 'black leather laced sneakers', price: 900}
    ]
  }
];

var actualFlatList = renderInventory(currentInventory);

var expectedFlatList = 'Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled black low-top lace-up, 1000\nBrunello Cucinelli, tasselled green low-top lace-up, 1100\nBrunello Cucinelli, plain beige suede moccasin, 950\nBrunello Cucinelli, plain olive suede moccasin, 1050\nGucci, red leather laced sneakers, 800\nGucci, black leather laced sneakers, 900\n';

assertEqual(actualFlatList, expectedFlatList, "should render flat list of inventory items");
```

**Result:** 
FAILED [should render flat list of inventory items] Expected "Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled black low-top lace-up, 1000
Brunello Cucinelli, tasselled green low-top lace-up, 1100
Brunello Cucinelli, plain beige suede moccasin, 950
Brunello Cucinelli, plain olive suede moccasin, 1050
Gucci, red leather laced sneakers, 800
Gucci, black leather laced sneakers, 900
", but got "Gucci, black leather laced sneakers, 900
'

I tried to add my code properly. Hopefully, I did it right. I'm a newbee in coding. My question is, this unit testing code block supposed to give **'passed'**. Where did I do wrong? Can someone clarify it please.

Comment: I guess whatever the function `renderInventory` is, it's not doing what you expect - if you `console.log(actualFlatList)` is it as you expect?

Comment: Check the spaces/new line/comma. Also, it will be really helpful if you print the result in the question.

Comment: Jaromanda X, yes you are right. ```var actualFlatList = renderInventory(currentInventory);```  is not doing the job. How can I fix this?

Comment: Spaces was mistaken, I fixed that. Still getting 'FAILED'

Answer (score 1):

I just found the problem. 
`flatList **+=** designerObject.name + ", " + currentShoe.name + ", " + currentShoe.price + '\n';`
It was missing an addition in the function renderInventory(inventory). Thank you!